# Ubuntu 22.04 boot stops and freezes

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04, dell

I have a Dell XPS 9720 that have a double boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. Yesterday I tried to download the Nvidia drivers (nvidia-driver-530).
When I reboot the system it freezes, with these errors:

```
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
pci 0000:00:07.1: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX Open Kernel Module for x86_64  530.41.03  Release Build  (dvs-builder@U16-T02-35-3)  Thu Mar 16 19:33:35 UTC 2023
dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature
```

I removed the driver that I installed with `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-530-open`, but I still get the errors on boot.

This is the output if i search for nvidia:

Results of `dpkg -l | grep  nvidia` :

[image]

kernel version: 5.19.0-41-generic

Comment: What errors on boot you need to add the errors to the question with edit. Do not put the info in a comment please.

Comment: Sorry is the first time im asking a question here, i put the errors i have in the code space at the top of the body question, is better practice to put i in the title or where ?

Comment: Not the title but where you feel is best in the body of the question. Not everyone can see the title like people using some phones wont see the title correctly.